Finding solutions to polynomial equations in a group algebra.
I'm thinking about a question that is to solve the equation $x^5 = x$ over the group algebra $\mathbb{C} G$ for $G = \mathbb{Z} / 7\mathbb{Z}$. However, I'm pretty lost. One option I was thinking of was to just solve
$$\left(\sum_{i = 0}^6 a_i g^i \right)^5 = \sum_{i = 0}^6 a_i g^i$$
but this would be really messy and not very enlightening. Secondly, I had the idea to try and use the spectral theorem, but the spectral theorem is more helpful in the other direction. $x^5 = x$ implies that $1 \not\in \text{spec}(x)$ where $$\text{spec}(x) = \{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C} \mid x - \lambda \text{ is not invertible in } \mathbb{C}G\}.$$
But generally $\text{spec}(x)$ is a small (and finite) set, so I don't think $1 \not\in \text{spec}(x)$ doesn't tell us much. I'm a little lost after this, and I'm really searching for a way that doesn't involve huge amounts of bashing, so it'd be great if I could get some help!

$x^5=x$ implies $x^8 = x^4$...

I'm sorry, could you expand just a tiny bit? I'm not clear how any polynomial equation works in this case unfortunately. Like, we can't even say that $x^4 = 1$ right as $\mathbb{C} G$ isn't even an integral domain, right? So I'm a little lost overall. Thanks for the help though!

$$\mathbb CG\cong \mathbb C[y]/\langle y^7-1\rangle\cong\mathbb C^7.$$ Unfortunately, while the isomorphism is relative easy in one direction, the inverse is a little harder. But there will be $5^7$ solutions.

@ThomasAndrews Hmm, this second isomorphism is as vector spaces right? As $\mathbb{C}^7$ is not naturally an algebra? Or am I being a little stupid?

No, $\mathbb C^7$ is the product of rings. @DanielNew

Specifically, if $\zeta_k=e^{2\pi k/7}$ are the $7$th roots of unity, then the map $\mathbb C[y]\to \mathbb C$ defined as $f(y)\mapsto f(\zeta_i)$ is a homomorphism and $\mathbb C[y]\mapsto \mathbb C^7$ defined as $f\mapsto (f(\zeta_0),\dots,f(\zeta_6))$ is a ring homomorphism with kernel $\langle y^7-1\rangle.$

Ohhhh, I think I completely understand now! Any tuple $(x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq 7}$ for $x_i^5 = x$ in $\mathbb{C}$ will be a solution then in $\mathbb{C}^7$, so we get the result. Thank you so much, that really helps! @ThomasAndrews

@Amateur_Algebraist I am curious as to your method, as it seems very different? Could you elaborate a little?

Well, it gives the number of solutions, easily, but you have to come up with the reverse isomorphism to find the $5^7$ answers. But that is a lot of answers, so you probably don't want to do that.

@ThomasAndrews Yep, I mean could you just essentially use the Lagrange interpolation formula? Although yeah, certainly won't be pretty.

Yeah, that's the easiest way, but it is messy.
